# Has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running my Vue app locally from http://localhost:8080 and I keep getting a slew of CORS errors, I've added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header as seen blow but keep getting the following warning:

' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
const graphCall = () => {

  let tokenOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/**key**/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080',
      'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },

    form: {
      grant_type: VUE_APP_GRANT_TYPE,
      client_secret: VUE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
      scope: VUE_APP_SCOPE,
      client_id: VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID
    }

  };

  return rp(tokenOptions)
    .then(data => {

      console.log(data)


    }).catch((err) => {

      console.log(err);

    });
};
```

I've tried adding mode: 'no-cors' but just get the following - Error: Invalid value for opts.mode

I've also tried '*' as the access control origin but to no avail.

Is there a way through this CORS nightmare as we need to make this call to retrieve a key!

Comment: stop putting **Response** headers (e.g. `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080',`) in a **Request** - that is triggering a CORS preflight (the options request) - remove it, see if that helps - read up on CORS, understand the difference between request and response - also understand that you can't tell the server to grant you access, it can tell you if you have access or not - otherwise the whole point of CORS (sites protecting their resources) would be meaninglass

Comment: wait ... this is in node? why would you be subject to CORS at all!!

Comment: @JaromandaX that's what was confusing me, initially I tried without using the ACAO but got the following error.  : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: seriously, nodejs doesn't need CORS headers - this is code in nodejs, not in the browser, correct?

Comment: @JaromandaX It's a js file that I'm importing into an authentication callback in my Vue app.

Comment: oh, so it's in the browser ... well, you can't beat CORS ... if your original error is "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" then the resource you're trying to obtain is **not** available from a browser - try making the request *through* your server

Answer (score 0):

The server has to allow your origin, in this case http://localhost:8080. Often in scenarios where you are interacting with a provider, in the admin portal where you create the tokens, you also have to specify the domain from which you intend on calling it from.

If this is not the case you may be triggering CORS because you are using a header not on the CORS safe list.
https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is normally the header supplied by the server on a response, it is not meant to be sent on the request.

The following link helped me understand CORS better.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Do note that allowing the origin of `*` is fine for development but not recommended for production applications.